# Symfony6 : App.User is null (Authenticated User is not saved) cause of token lost after redirection

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, web-application-firewall

I am working in Symfony5.3 application (released in 2020 or 2021 I guess), and I have to take it over and upgrade its version to Symfony6.2.
Well, I am facing some problems during authentications, after calling app.user.username in my html.twig file I got : Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a null variable.
Well, i see app.user is null even after successful login, the User is not correctly set to app.

And I don't know what's missing, here is my code:

security.yaml

```
security:
    providers:
        database_users:
            id: App\Security\UsersProvider
    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\Users:
            algorithm: sha512
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: database_users
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: /login
                invalidate_session: true
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthentificator
```

LoginForm

```
class LoginFormAuthentificator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator 
    use TargetPathTrait;
    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'login';
    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $userProvider;
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager,
     UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    }
    ...
    ...
        public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $providerKey): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('researchGeneral'));
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport {

        $encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordHasher('sha512', true, 5000);
        $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($request->request->get("username"));
        if (!$user) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid credentials.');
        }

        $verif = $encoder->verify($user->getPassword(), $request->request->get("password"), 'sha512');
        if (!$verif) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid credentials.');
        }

        return new SelfValidatingPassport(new UserBadge($request->request->get("username")));
    }
```

SecurityController

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        if ($this->getUser()) {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('researchGeneral');
        }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }
```

It's not the full code of each file, but I presented the code snippet I believe are concerned by this.

[EDIT]
The exact problem is losing the access token after redirecting.

Comment: Where did you get the `LoginFormAuthentificator::authenticate` code from?  Out of the box, 6.2 uses a Passport based approach.  You would not directly (for example) access the hasher or do password verification yourself.  Not saying your approach will not work but it is unusual.  You might consider creating a new 6.2 project, run `make:user` and `make:auth` and just get a working example of authentication to compare against.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering,
I did what you asked me, and implemented the authentication using a passport approach, but i do still have the same problem, when crawling the web, i found a lot of ppl got the same problem but no one provided a straightforward answer.
Anyway, the problem is when redirect we do lose the token (the session is completly changed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a lot of research, i found the problem, it was the method hasUserChanged in Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener it detected an undesirable de-authentication because i've some mistakes on my userProvider.

Anyway if you have encountered this problem, app.user null, or token changed after redirection is 100% due to malfunction of your components (provider or entity or security config or smth so) and it's really hard that someone can debug it for you.